# Implementacion correcta de Promesas de javascript Chaining

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Hice una implementación de Promises de Javascript y quisiera que me dieran un feedback de como lo he hecho. Yo pienso que no lo estoy haciendo correctamente en lo que se refiere al chainning, ademas porque en el código tengo varios niveles de indentacion. Casi que se parecen a Callbacks

```
var voladura = ctx.match[0].toUpperCase();

playground.getTelegramFileId(voladura)
.then(volObj=>{
    ctx.replyWithChatAction('upload_photo');
    ctx.replyWithPhoto(volObj.file_id,{
        caption: `Pozos planeados: ${volObj.pozos_planeados}\n`
    })
    .then(results => {
        console.log(`Voladura ${voladura} enviada`)
    });
})
.catch(err =>{

    generateCanvas.createImageXLSXPro(voladura)
    .then((pozosObj)=> {
        ctx.replyWithChatAction('typing');
        ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: fs.readFileSync(`./images/${voladura}.png`)},{
            caption: `⚫️ Pozos planeados: ${pozosObj.plan}`
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(voladura);
            playground.saveTelegramFileId(voladura, pozosObj, result)
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
            fs.exists(`./images/${voladura}.png`,(exists)=>{
                if (exists) {
                    fs.unlinkSync(`./images/${voladura}.png`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`No se encontro la imagen ${voladura}.png`)
                }
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        ctx.reply(`No se encontraron datos de la voladura ${voladura}. ` );
    });
})
```

Comment: Podrías explicar qué esperas que haga tu código. ¿Está funcionando ahora?